# Parse json string in java : Unexpected character (P) at position 1

Tags: java, json

i 'm trying to parse json string represented as follows : 
[json viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Izx.png)

```
{PurchAdBidderBidRequest:{div:"lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic"}}
```

currently i'm using this code which leads to given exception `Unexpected character (P) at position 1.`
, please suggest how to resolve as the i have googled this error but my json is little different from the other issue i have found here related to this.

```
System.out.println(jstring);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject js = null;
            try {
                js = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jstring);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Before : "+ (new JSONObject(js)));
```

Comment: Your string is not in proper JSON format.

Comment: any idea , how to convert in proper format

Comment: What is the parser you are using? Show the import statement in the code.

Comment: Anyway, this is not JSON.

Comment: The object that you are using is not JSON, so no JSON parser will work on it. There are only 2 ways, either convert the object to be a proper JSON or write your own parser. From the screenshot, it look like it has been improperly serialized because the object you are refering to is used in javascript. It is a valid javascript syntax but unfortunately not a valid JSON.

`> a = {PurchAdBidderBidRequest:{div:"lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic"}}
{ PurchAdBidderBidRequest: { div: 'lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic' } }`
`> a.PurchAdBidderBidRequest
{ div: 'lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic' }
>
`

Comment: can you check this image for refernce https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Izx.png'

Comment: This is valid JSON:
`
{
    "PurchAdBidderBidRequest": {
        "div": "lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic"
    }
}
`
You can always go to a site like https://jsonlint.com to see if your json is valid. Or paste it into a text editor that has syntax highlighting and save it as a .json file.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON format keys have to by quoted.

Try this:

{"PurchAdBidderBidRequest":{"div":"lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic"}}

Comment: i cant change the format , please suggest any other way

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that it's a valid Javascript syntax and can be evaluated gave me an idea to use the [Nashorn Javascript Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) which is implemented in Java and is available in jdk distribution by default.

So you can tinker with that string from the image, which I believe is a string and not an Object, i.e. you can get the value as `"{PurchAdBidderBidRequest:{div:\"lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic\"}}"` and not `{PurchAdBidderBidRequest:{div:"lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic"}}`.

A small working example:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;

class BadJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();

        String v = "v = {PurchAdBidderBidRequest:{div:\"lmhovttghyiifbwnzktyzmqic\"}}";

        JSObject res = (JSObject)(engine.eval(v));
        System.out.println(((JSObject)(res.getMember("PurchAdBidderBidRequest"))).getMember("div"));
    }
}
```

I think you can now get creative with this to parse whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

when you meet a letter and in front of it not have Double quotes.

then you add Double quotes

when you find ":" or "}" and in front of it not have Double quotes

then you add Double quotes

Comment: my english is bad  wish i can help you  even it is not a smart way.    In fact i want tell you that JSON format is wrong, you should better tell your API colleague change the format